# single sign on in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

We have developed implemented single sign on methodology to authenticate user.

When a page is requested, if it is not authenticated then a login page will be redirected. Once they logged in the requested page will be shown.

this is working when we don't assign a domain to the virtual directory. But when we assign the domain to virtual directory after the authentication the application is not redirecting to the requested page.

We are using FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl method to redirect the requested page.

Why this is happening? How can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check Windows Identity Framework too.

Good article here : [Windows Identity Foundation features for passive single sign-on and single sign-out](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/security-development/Implementing-Single-Sign-On-and-Sign-Out-in-ASP-NET-Apps.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

First add defaulturl to your web.config and see if page can redirect to defaulturl after authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
        <forms loginUrl = "login.aspx" defaultUrl="default.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

If defaulturl works then you have to check ReturnUrl parameter in your login page address